# Can you track the users location in a shared global class?

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

I have a global shared class which I use to make certain data available from anywhere in my app. One thing I have been trying to achieve is to track the users location and save those coordinates in this global shared class.

I have tried implementing all the necessary components, which I had working in its old class, but when doing so I am forced to add some protocol stubs, which I am not sure what to do with.

Additionally I get an error on the line `func`self`() -> Self {`

This is the code:

```
  extension GlobalSharedData: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
       <#code#>
   }

   var hash: Int {
       <#code#>
   }

   var superclass: AnyClass? {
       <#code#>
   }

   func `self`() -> Self {
       <#code#>
   }

   func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>! {
       <#code#>
   }

   func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!, with object: Any!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>! {
       <#code#>
   }

   func perform(_ aSelector: Selector!, with object1: Any!, with object2: Any!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>! {
       <#code#>
   }

   func isProxy() -> Bool {
       <#code#>
   }

   func isKind(of aClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
       <#code#>
   }

   func isMember(of aClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
       <#code#>
   }

   func conforms(to aProtocol: Protocol) -> Bool {
       <#code#>
   }

   func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool {
       <#code#>
   }

   var description: String {
       <#code#>
   }
```

**Can this be done? If so how?**

Comment: The current location of a user isn't something you should store, because by its nature it's a value that's prone to change over time. There's a reason why `CoreLocation` doesn't provide the location as a variable, but as a call back through which you subscribe to receive location changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you missed subclassing `NSObject`

```
import Foundation

import CoreLocation

protocol LocationServiceDelegate {
    func tracingLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation)
    func tracingLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError)
}

class LocationSingleton: NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var lastLocation: CLLocation?
    var delegate: LocationServiceDelegate?

    static let shared:LocationSingleton = {
        let instance = LocationSingleton()
        return instance
    }()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        guard let locationManagers=self.locationManager else {
            return
        }

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            locationManagers.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManagers.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            //            locationManagers.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        locationManagers.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManagers.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManagers.distanceFilter = 0.1
        locationManagers.delegate = self

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        self.lastLocation = location
        updateLocation(currentLocation: location)

    }

    @nonobjc func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .restricted:
            // restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services
            break
        case .denied:
            // user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }



    // Private function
    private func updateLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation){

        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }

        delegate.tracingLocation(currentLocation: currentLocation)
    }

    private func updateLocationDidFailWithError(error: NSError) {

        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }

        delegate.tracingLocationDidFailWithError(error: error)
    }

    func startUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Starting Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        //        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    func stopUpdatingLocation() {
        print("Stop Location Updates")
        self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges() {
        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }

    // #MARK:   get the alarm time from date and time
}
```

---

To use

```
LocationSingleton.shared.delegate = self //optional inside the vc
LocationSingleton.shared.startUpdatingLocation() // start this as earlier as possible so when you check of lastLocation is could have a value
```